# NodeJS Conditional Decision Making

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to do a simple if-else in NodeJS.

as per the information about the syntax it looks correct.

However no matter what if block is not working. Neither the msg variable value is getting updated.

Code:

```
sql.connect(config, function(err) {
console.log(err)
var r = new sql.Request();
r.input('gc', sql.VarChar, gcode);
r.input('ingt',sql.VarChar, gtype);
r.input('incf',sql.VarChar,gconfig);
r.input('ingp',sql.VarChar, gprovider);
r.input('inld',sql.DateTime2, launchdate)
r.input('in_activefrom',sql.DateTime2, date_activeFrom)
r.input('in_activeto',sql.DateTime2, date_activeTo)
r.multiple = true;

var rec_count = 0;
r.query("select * from md.GameMasters WHERE gameCode=@gc",function(err, result){
    rec_count = result['recordset'].length;
    console.log('Existing Records: ' + rec_count)
})

if(Number(rec_count) >0){
    console.log('Multiple record exist')
    msg = "Record Exist in Database";
}
else{
    r.query("INSERT INTO md.GameMasters(gameCode,gtype,config,grovider,launchdate,activefrom,activeto,recordEntryOn) VALUES(@gc,@ingt,@incf,@ingp,@inld,@in_activefrom,@in_activeto,getdate())",function(err,result){
        console.log(result['rowsAffected'][0])
        console.log('Record Inserted')
    })
    msg = 'Record Added';
}

});
```

Wanted to know what part went wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: i don't think so. I saw the answer but can't co-relate

Comment: It's the same, you just can't correlate. :). Simply you cannot access the variable outside of callback without using the following methods explained in the post.

Comment: Everything you want to happen after the query has finished needs to be moved inside the `function(err, result)` callback. It's very much a duplicate of that question. It's a *very* common issue, and easily identifiable.

Answer (score 1):

Being `query()` is asynchronous your `if...else` is executing way before the variable is updated, include that inside call back function:

```
......
r.query("select * from md.GameMasters WHERE gameCode=@gc",function(err, result){
  rec_count = result['recordset'].length;
  console.log('Existing Records: ' + rec_count);

  if(Number(rec_count) >0){
    console.log('Multiple record exist')
    msg = "Record Exist in Database";
  }
  else{
    r.query("INSERT INTO md.GameMasters(gameCode,gtype,config,grovider,launchdate,activefrom,activeto,recordEntryOn) VALUES(@gc,@ingt,@incf,@ingp,@inld,@in_activefrom,@in_activeto,getdate())",function(err,result){
        console.log(result['rowsAffected'][0])
        console.log('Record Inserted');
        msg = 'Record Added';
    });
  }
});
.....
```

Comment: this solved the issue of if-else, but the msg variable is still not updating? Any idea how to go about that?

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal, same reason, update the `msg` inside the inner request call back function, updated the answer:)

Comment: I tried with the modification on the location of the msg variable. Still It is not getting updated

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal, do you see `console.log('Record Inserted');` is showing the message in console?

Comment: Yes. I see record inserted on console

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal, then there could be some other issue, as it is straight forward code...